# BBM chat integration in 3rd party App

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, bb-messenger

i want to integrate BBM Api in my application where i can chat with my friends without switching to BBM app.

I know, i can initate the chat to any contact , but is it possible to receive messages into my app and continue chatting ?

Any input on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to receive BBM chat messages within your application on BlackBerry 10.

If you open the BBM Chat card from your application with a user you already have a BBM conversation with, the chat history is shown.  But you can't get the actual chat content within your application.

Comment: got it answered at http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/BBM-API-integration/td-p/3129819#M74371